# Apple Mail search very slow (Big Sur)

Tags: macos, mail.app, spotlight

Mail searches used to be lightning fast and results appeared as I typed. For the last few months, they're been super slow (macOS 11.5.2, rMBP 2015). I have just one account with less than 2GB of mail.

I've tried all the usual tricks, deleting and re-adding my account, `sudo mdutil -E /` to rebuild Spotlight indexes, and deleting `Envelope Index`. Didn't help.

Spotlight outside Mail operates normally.

Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Same thing happened to me around the same time — hoped Apple would fix it but I'm on Monterey now and still slow as molasses!

Comment: I don't remember, but it's working now; I might have deleted and re-added the account.